How to create AppEntity shortcut to be shown in Spotlight
I am exploring Appi-Intent and Appshortcut. We can create an action shortcut by using the following code.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10102/
struct WatchListShortcut: AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        AppShortcut(
            intent: WatchListAppIntent(),
            phrases: [
                "Tell \(.applicationName) to open first item in watch list",

            ],
            shortTitle: "WatchList item",
            systemImageName: "systemimage"
        )
    }
    
}

What I want to show an entity shortcut like shown in the below screenshot.

I am not sure how to create the shortcut like Assigned one in the above screen.
Right now the AppShortcut only accepts systemImage how can I use custom image?

Are you asking how to make a shortcut like Assigned from your screenshots? or Want to modify your shortcut icon in the search bar?

try set systemImageName a real value . like "pin".
        shortTitle: "WatchList item",
        systemImageName: "pin"


var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
    DisplayRepresentation(
        title: LocalizedStringResource(stringLiteral: name ),
        subtitle: "Door",
        image: .init(named: image!),
        synonyms: ["Gate"]
    )
}

where name & image are defined as:
@Property(title: "Name")
var name: String

@Property(title: "Image")
var image: String?

